# Why was this question made a Wiki?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, community-wiki

This SO question: [Using Randomize() before Rnd() in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380990/using-randomize-before-rnd-in-vb-net) is now a wiki and the OP doesn't know why. I can't see any reason either. Is there any way to figure out why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Owner made it wiki

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1380990/list

see comment on initial revision

Comment: Looks like they didn't know wiki hit them.

Comment: That just did not sound punny enough.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with random, and since the question has no edit history it is also possible that a Moderator flipped the CW switch. In these cases the question edit history is not updated, and all questions and answer, existing or otherwise is flipped to CW mode.

I would flag it for moderator attention to confirm, unfortunately there is no way to revert back.

Comment: I flagged it and will see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

It's not due from the amount of questions, that's well below the auto-wiki threshold for SO.

It's possible that they accidentally set the checkbox for community wiki when editing within the 5 minute grace period.

Possible steps:

- Post question
- Edit within 5 minute grace
- Double tab to skip Edit Summary and jump right to <kbd>Save Your Edits</kbd>
- Accidentally tabbed again and hit                         to end up with ☑ community wiki
- Realise the form is not moving
- Click on <kbd>Save Your Edits</kbd> with mouse
- Question and all subsequent answers now community wiki.

Comment: Yes, possible but I posted an answer and I'm almost sure it wasn't a Wiki then. But I may have missed it.

Comment: I also experienced this. I actually noticed in my edit history that one of the changes said "Made Community Wiki" as one of the changes made in that edit. I guess this indicates that it was me that made it wiki by accidentally ticking it, and that it was not done by a moderator...